# This code looks like it deletes this object but it doesnt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

the following code is for removing a node of a binary tree. I have stepped through the code and I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the last "else if" in destroy(). I'm trying to replace a given node with a smallest node then delete that given node. remove() and findsmallest work like they should I think. when I reprint the tree its like no changes have been made.I'm obviously a beginner, so any hints/help will be much appreciated!

```
void remove(Key k) 
{
    remove(k, root);
}
void remove(Key k, BinarySearchTreeNode<Key, Value> * n)
{
    if (n)
    {
        if (root->key == k)
            removeRoot();
        else
        {
            //1 child
            if ( (n->left != nullptr) && (k < n->key) )
            {
                if (k == n->left->key)
                    destroy(n->left, true);
                else
                    remove(k, n->left);
            }
            else if (n->right && k > n->key )
            {
                if (k == n->right->key)
                    destroy(n->right, false);
                else
                    remove(k, n->right);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "no remove\n";
            }
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "trww is empty";
}

void destroy(BinarySearchTreeNode<Key, Value> * n, bool isLeft)
{
    if (n == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (!n->left && !n->right)
    {
        n->left = nullptr;
        n->right = nullptr;
        n->parent = nullptr;
        delete n;
        n = nullptr;
    }
    else if (!n->left && n->right)
    {
        isLeft ? n->parent->left = n->right : n->parent->right = n->right;
        cout << "killing " << n->key << endl;
        n->parent = nullptr;
        n->left = nullptr;
        n->right = nullptr;
        delete n;
        n = nullptr;
    }
    else if (n->left && !n->right)
    {
        isLeft ? n->parent->left = n->left : n->parent->right = n->left;
        cout << "killing " << n->key << endl;
        n->parent = nullptr;
        n->left = nullptr;
        n->right = nullptr;
        delete n;
        n = nullptr;
    }
/* The program goes to the code below*/
    else if (n->left && n->right)
    {
        BinarySearchTreeNode<Key, Value> * small = findSmallest(n->right);
        if (isLeft)
            n->parent->left  = small;
        else
            n->parent->right = small;

        small->parent = n->parent;
        small->left = n->left;
        small->right = n->right;
        n->parent = nullptr; 
        n->left = nullptr;
        n->right = nullptr;
        //Key smallKey = small->key;
        //Value smallValue = small->value;
        cout << "killing " << n->key << endl;
        delete n;
        n = nullptr;

    }
    else
        cout << "fail";


}

BinarySearchTreeNode<Key, Value> * findSmallest(BinarySearchTreeNode<Key, Value> * n)
{
    if (!n)
        return part;
    else 
    {
        if (n->left)
            return findSmallest(n->left);
        else
            return n;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You give the node to `destroy()` as a pointer. This means you can do all the things you did, except change the variable in to calling method.

When you say `n= nullptr;` in `destroy()` it only changes the *local* variable. It doesn't change the *calling* variable, for example `n->right` to `nullptr` so it will still point to the place where the deleted object was.

If you set the parameter to be a reference to a pointer (`*&`) you can change the calling variable and actually remove the pointer to the node.

The reason why it looks like the original tree is because the memory allocated to the deleted node happened not to be reused yet. Later it would be and your tree would cause access to a wrong pointer and maybe crash. The behaviour is undefined.